# A single libname with multiple paths in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm specifically doing some work in DI studio and I've come across something I don't understand.

We work on a Unix GRID platform.

There's a metadata library object that has the following notation:

```
library test ("/gpfs/data/location1" "/gpfs/data/location2");
```

I've never actually seen this notation before. Is it the datasets from each library or something?

Answer (score 3):

It's a concatenated library - the first directory (`"/gpfs/data/location1"`) is searched before the second (`"/gpfs/data/location2"`).

If a dataset exists in the first AND the second, then the first one is used.  Similar approaches can be used for the SASAUTOs location, and filerefs..

See [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000933322.htm) for further info.